# Get Employee details

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a excel sheet containing a Employee Details data like (Employee name, Employee ID, Email id, First Name, Last name, Location, Group, Joining Date etc).
I have the below Working code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\UserList.xlsx')
df = df[df['Emp Num'].isin(['X902', '342','983','X910'])]
df.to_excel("Output1.xlsx",index=False)

import os
file = "Output1.xlsx"
os.startfile(file)
```

But the issue is when i run this code i get employees  details of (X910,X902)only, i am not getting the details of employees id (342,983). Basically with that code i get all employees details starting with "X" but not getting the details with employees ID starting with number (Eg:342,983,444,890 etc)
Can someone guide me how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this! Also first make sure that the columns name matches the names in `usecols`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file_loc = "UserList.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "X902,342,983,X910")
df.to_excel("Output1.xlsx",index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps check that the column 'Emp Num' cell values are set to the number format 'Text'. If they are set to 'General' then they may be parsed through as integers rather than string values.

[image: You change it from here]

Comment: removed  the quotation marks and when i run it i am able to get the details as required. Also changed number format to text.

Comment: one small query regarding this, Right now i manually enter the employee ID here to get the details df = df[df['Emp Num'].isin(['X902', 342,983,'X910'])] . How do i modify code if i have a excel sheet containing Employee ID details. Basically i have a excel sheet containing employee ID only, for those employee ID i need complete empyoee details

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you remove the quotation marks around the number IDs, like so:

```
df = df[df['Emp Num'].isin(['X902', 342,983,'X910'])]
```

You could also avoid having to do this by setting the cell type for the Num Emp column in Excel to 'Text'

Comment: removed  the quotation marks and when i run it i am able to get the details as required. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: one small query regarding this, Right now i manually enter the employee ID here to get the details  `df = df[df['Emp Num'].isin(['X902', 342,983,'X910'])]` . How do i modify code if i have a excel sheet containing  Employee ID details. Basically i have a excel sheet containing employee ID only, for those employee ID i need complete empyoee details.